# Why can't we use set(setter) without a get(getter)?

Tags: apex, getter, setter

I need to just display the result of the user input field in following code:

```
public class EX_1 {
public Integer i1{set;}
public Integer i2{set;}
public Integer result=i1+i2;
public Integer display(){
    return result;
}
}
```

Here, i1 and i2 are the field values that user will fill within a visualforce page and result is the variable to be displayed. But this is showing error

```
Variable is not visible: EX_1.i1
Variable is not visible: EX_1.i2
```

Please explain this.

Comment: `getter` is required for the page to know about the property. With `setter` a controller can modify the property value. hence setter needs getter.

Comment: You can use a setter without a getter. But that makes the property write-only. Not sure if it's actually possible to reference in Visualforce but property syntax does support it.